# Compression of a video with constant background

Tags: ffmpeg, background, video-encoding

(sorry if my english is bad, I can read it but I don't write it quite well...)

I want to compress some videos, which have two particularities:

- there is a background that covers ~90% of the area, during the whole video
- most of the others elements can be separately described by a picture in move

My videos are like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrXS5UiCa50), and don't have audio. As you can see, almost everything can be described only by using a fixed background, few small images in move, plus a noise. Moreover, this noise will be almost nul and then an entropic coding would be very efficient. I think it will produce tiny files (< 5 Mo) even if the duration is in hours, a result that is very appreciable since I have actually recorded ~30h of game (actual size is 3 Go).

Is there any way to get new video files, that benefit of these informations? If yes, what are the implication of a such encoding for watching these videos with Windows Media Player, or for usage with ffmpeg?

I searched with Google after anything that can help me, but I don't know which keyword I can use for this, then I didn't found anything usefull :-(

Thanks in advance :-)

PS: [another example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJ4aJWoKWTc), the video is accelerated but shows the interesting moves

Answer (score 1):

x264/5 will automatically allocate fewer bits to static parts. Your size will depend on keyframe frequency (`-g N`, `N` is is frames) and overall quality level (`-crf X`). There are a few other parameters you can tweak, but none will result in a < 5MB output for videos that is hours long.

Comment: I tried this, and can get slightly better results than my original command line (ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec h264 -qscale:v 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4). Do you have an idea about the moving elements? Is it possible to indicate to ffmpeg a list of images that will often appear? Like that it can do "for this frame, the 3rd picture appears at position (x, y)" or something like this

Comment: No. But that's essentially what the encoder does anyway. It generates motion vectors i.e. these group of pixels move to the right in the next frame. However, the horizon is narrow and won't connect a set of pixels to an earlier occurrence in a frame 20 seconds earlier. For your given content, it may be worth exploring Flash.

Comment: Without much experience with h265, i could imagine h265's advantage to h264 might in this case even bigger than the general (expected) compression advantage, due to macroblock->ctu replacement (of course the encoder always plays a big role; VP9 should be comparable).